Is $\int_{\tau_0}^{\tau_1}f(W_t)\mathrm{d}t$ independent of $\mathcal{F}_{\tau_0}$ for some stopng times $\tau_0, \tau_1$ and Lebesgue integrable $f$?
Let $W=(W_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be the standard Brownian motion, let $X_t=W_t+X_0$ with initial distribution $X_0\sim\delta_x$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, let $\tau_1^1=\tau^1=\inf\{t>0:X_t=1\}$, write $\tau_0^1=\tau_0=\inf\{t>\tau^1:X_t=0\}$ and in general write
$$
\tau_1^n=\inf\{t>\tau_0^{n-1}:X_t=1\}\quad\tau_0^n=\inf\{t>\tau_1^n:X_t=0\}.
$$
From this question, by the amazing help of the community, I know that for general $s\leq t$, that $\int_s^t f(W_u)\mathrm{d}u$ is in general not independent to $\mathcal{F}_s$, which now makes complete sense as the level at which we enter the interval $[s,t]$ clearly is dependent on $\mathcal{F}_s$ and dictates the output of the intergral.
However, if $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is arbitrary, then what can we say about the (in)dependence of
$$
I(n)=\int_{\tau_0^{n-1}}^{\tau_0^n}f(W_t)\mathrm{d}t
$$
to $\mathcal{F}_{\tau_0^{n-1}}$. I would say that they should be independent, given that at for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $W_{\tau_0^n}=0$, and so $(W_{\tau_0^n+t})_{t\geq 0}$ is just another Brownian motion, with the property that $W_{\tau_0^n+t}\sim W_{t}$ for all $t$. Hence, it must then only logically follow that indeed $I(n)$ is independent to $\mathcal{F}_{\tau_0^{n-1}}$, however I am not seeing how to prove (or disprove) this rigorously.
Any help is welcome!
To give some information on why this is interesting, I am trying to use some form of the law of large numbers, and to do, I need to show the independence of the random variables $Y_j=\int_{\tau_0^{j}}^{\tau_0^{j+1}}f(W_t)\mathrm{d}t$. Now if the above indeed holds, then we may conclude that $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of independenet and identically distributed random variables.

Just to check, should that be $\tau_0^{n-1}$ as the lower bound of the integral in $I(n)$, instead of $t_0^{n-1}$?

@user6247850, yes you are right! I changed it!

It follows from the strong Markov property of Brownian motion.  We know $W_{\tau_0^{n-1} + t} - W_{\tau_0^{n-1}}$ is independent of $\mathcal F_{\tau_0^{n-1}}$, and since $W_{\tau_0^{n-1}} = 0$, we have $W_{\tau_0^{n-1} + t}$ is independent of $\mathcal F_{\tau_0^{n-1}}$.    Standard change of variables gives
\begin{align*}
I(n) &= \int_{\tau_0^{n-1}}^{\tau_0^n} f(W_t) dt \\
&= \int_0^{\tau_0^{n}-\tau_0^{n-1}} f(W_{\tau_0^{n-1} + t}) dt.
\end{align*}
Observe that $\sigma_1^n := \inf\{t > 0 : W_{\tau_0^{n-1} + t} = 1\} = \tau_1^n - \tau_0^{n-1}$ and $\sigma_0^n  := \inf\{t > \sigma_1^n : W_{\tau_0^{n-1} + t} = 0\} =  \tau_1^n - \tau_0^{n-1}$ are both measurable with respect to the filtration generated by $W_{\tau_0^{n-1} + t}$.  Therefore $I(n)$ is measurable with respect to the filtration generated by $W_{\tau_0^{n-1} + t}$, and hence independent of $\mathcal F_{\tau_0^{n-1}}$.
